# iOS - Callback everytime the displayed view changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, key-value-observing

I would like to know if there is anyway I could get a callback everytime the displayed view changes and receive the newly displayed view as a parameter of the callback?

Can this be achieved with the key-value observing protocol?

Here is more details: I develop an SDK so I don't know what the client app is doing wrt controllers but I would like to know every time a new view controller is presented by the client app. Or in other terms, I would like to know when the displayed view on the UIWindow changes.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What kind of view is this? How is it being updated? Is it a view you created or one from some third party library?

Comment: I'm talking about the UIWindow of the app i.e. the main view updated everytime a new view controller is presented.

Comment: Why? Ask about the problem you are trying to solve, now what you think the solution might be. View changes are driven by your data so observe that.

Comment: @Wain: I want to do this in an SDK that would be integrated in an app I don't control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the recipe that solves my problem: http://broutille.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/ios-how-to-monitor-the-change-of-viewcontrollers-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/.

That and adding an observer for the "UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification" notification.